Laravel AuthenticatedSessionControllerTest Fails with 404 for Login and Logout Tests
I am encountering an issue with testing the login and logout functionalities in my Laravel application. When I run the test suite, some tests fail with a 404 status code instead of the expected 401 or 200. Interestingly, when I run each test individually, they work perfectly fine. Below is my test code:
class AuthenticatedSessionControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_user_can_login_with_valid_credentials()
    {

        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password123'),
        ]);
        $response = $this->postJson('/api/v1/login', [
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'password123',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                'success',
                'accessToken',
                'token_type',
                'message',
                'data' => ['id', 'name', 'email'],
                'roles',
                'permissions',
            ]);
    }

    public function test_user_cannot_login_with_invalid_credentials()
    {
        $response = $this->postJson('/api/v1/login', [
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'wrongpassword',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records',
            ]);
    }

    public function test_user_can_logout()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password123'),
        ]);
        Sanctum::actingAs($user);

        $response = $this->postJson('/api/v1/login', [
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'password123',
        ]);
        $response = $this->postJson('/api/v1/logout');

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Successfully logged out',
            ]);

        $this->assertCount(0, $user->tokens);
    }
}


What could be causing these tests to fail with 404 only when run together? Is there something I am missing with state handling in Laravel or Sanctum?

It seems like you may have some issues with route matching when running the tests in the suite. Can you share details about your authentication setup (e.g., Passport, Sanctum) ?
BTW, for failed authentication, you should be getting a 401 Unauthorized response, not a 404 or 200. You can use dd($response) to check what is return on posted JSON.

Answer should provide a clear solution .
Comments are intended for clarifications , if you need more clarification on the op question I suggest you put that as comment .

Thank you for your clarification! I’m using Laravel Sanctum for authentication
